# Resolving AmbiguousTimeError from Django's make_aware

Tags: python, django, timezone, dst

I have a code as follows:

```
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone, make_aware

make_aware(some_datetime, get_current_timezone())
```

The `make_aware` call occasionally raises

```
AmbiguousTimeError: 2013-11-03 01:23:17
```

I know from the Django docs that this is a daylight savings problem, and that this timestamp is in fact ambiguous.  Now how do i resolve it (say to the first of the two possible times this could be)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Prophylactics

You should avoid naive datetimes in the first place using the following:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

If like me, you have naive times already that you must convert, read on!

### Django 4+:

Starting in Django 4, if you use `zoneinfo` for [timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) (which is the default in Django 4) there's nothing you need to do to use `make_aware` to avoid this error.  The `is_dst` flag to make_aware is deprecated in Django 4 and will be removed in Django 5.

### Django 1.9 - 3.2:

You can resolve the AmbiguousTimeError by using the following ([thanks to GeyseR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583232/2800876)):

```
from django.utils import timezone

# This uses `settings.TIME_ZONE` unless you call `timezone.activate()`
timezone.make_aware(some_datetime, is_dst=False)
```

### Django 1.x - 1.8:

The problem is that make_aware just calls timezone.localize, passing None to the argument is_dst:

```
timezone.localize(value, is_dst=None)
```

The argument is_dst is specifically what is used to resolve this ambiguous time error (http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api).

The solution is to call timezone.localize yourself:

```
get_current_timezone().localize(some_datetime, is_dst=False)
```

Having is_dst=False sets it to the first of the two possible times.  is_dst=True would be the second.

Comment: a better solution would be to avoid naive datetime objects if possible e.g., as [@Michael van de Waeter has suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33325230/4279). Note: `localize(is_dst=False)` may produce a non-existent time, call `.normalize()` to adjust it, see  ["Can I just always set is_dst=True?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727761/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks so much, that was super constructive.

Answer (score 6):

Since django 1.9 make_aware utility function has `is_dst` parameter.
So you can use it for solving AmbiguousTimeError exception:

```
    from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone, make_aware

    make_aware(some_datetime, get_current_timezone(), is_dst=True)
```

or

```
    make_aware(some_datetime, get_current_timezone(), is_dst=False)
```

[Related section in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware)

Answer (score 3):

For people searching on this error:

In your Django code, replace:

```
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
```

with

```
    from django.utils import timezone

    today = timezone.now()
```

Comment: Indeed, it may fix the root cause (naive datetimes are generated -- if `today` is the single source of datetime objects). You should use `USE_TZ=True`, otherwise `timezone.now()` also returns naive datetime objects.