# python converting string in localtime to UTC epoch timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I have strings in YMD hms format that had the timezone stripped. But I know they are in Eastern time with daylight savings time.

I am trying to convert them into epoch timestamps for UTC time.

I wrote the following function:

```
def ymdhms_timezone_dst_to_epoch(input_str,  tz="US/Eastern"):
    print(input_str)
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(input_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    local_dt = pytz.timezone(tz).localize(dt)
    print(local_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
    utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    print(utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))    
    e = int(utc_dt.strftime("%s"))
    print(e)
    return e

Given string `2015-04-20 21:12:07` this prints:

    2015-04-20 21:12:07
    2015-04-20 21:12:07 EDT-0400 #<- so far so good?
    2015-04-21 01:12:07 UTC+0000 #<- so far so good?
    1429596727
```

which looks ok up to the epoch timestamp. But http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1429596727 says it should mao to 
Greenwich Mean Time Apr 21 2015 06:12:07 UTC.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have strings in YMD hms format that had the timezone stripped. But I know they are in Eastern time with daylight savings time.

A portable way is to use `pytz`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

naive_dt = datetime.strptime('2015-04-20 21:12:07', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
eastern_dt = tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive_dt))
print(eastern_dt)
# -> 2015-04-20 21:12:07-04:00
```

> I am trying to convert them into epoch timestamps for UTC time.

```
timestamp = (eastern_dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
# -> 1429578727.0
```

See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

---

There are multiple issues in your code:

- `time.mktime()` may return a wrong result for ambiguous input time (50% chance) e.g., during "fall back" DST transition in the Fall
- `time.mktime()` and `datetime.fromtimestamp()` may fail for past/future dates if they have no access to a historical timezone database on a system (notably, Windows)
- `localize(dt)` may return a wrong result for ambiguous or non-existent time i.e., during DST transitions. If you know that the time corresponds to the summer time then use `is_dst=True`. `tz.normalize()` is necessary here, to adjust possible non-existing times in the input
- [`utc_dt.strftime("%s")` is not portable and it does not respect tzinfo object](http://bugs.python.org/issue12750). It interprets input as a local time i.e., it returns a wrong result unless your local timezone is UTC.

---

> Can I just always set is_dst=True?

You can, if you don't mind getting imprecise results for ambiguous or non-existent times e.g., there is DST transition in the Fall in America/New_York time zone:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz # $ pip install pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> ambiguous_time = datetime(2015, 11, 1, 1, 30)
>>> time_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z (%Z)'
>>> tz.localize(ambiguous_time).strftime(time_fmt)
'2015-11-01 01:30:00-0500 (EST)'
>>> tz.localize(ambiguous_time, is_dst=False).strftime(time_fmt) # same
'2015-11-01 01:30:00-0500 (EST)'
>>> tz.localize(ambiguous_time, is_dst=True).strftime(time_fmt) # different
'2015-11-01 01:30:00-0400 (EDT)'
>>> tz.localize(ambiguous_time, is_dst=None).strftime(time_fmt) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2015-11-01 01:30:00
```

The clocks are turned back [at 2a.m. on the first Sunday in November](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/aedb557c7034c26480d0fc2755871bd6355ba6e2/northamerica#L135):

[image: clocks are turned back]

`is_dst` disambiguation flag may have three values:

- `False` -- default, assume the winter time
- `True` -- assume the summer time
- `None` -- raise an exception for ambiguous/non-existent times.

`is_dst` value is ignored for existing unique local times.

Here's a plot from [PEP 0495 -- Local Time Disambiguation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0495/) that illustrates the DST transition:
[image: utc vs. local time in the fold]

The local time repeats itself twice in the fold (summer time -- before the fold, winter time -- after).

To be able to disambiguate the local time automatically, you need some additional info e.g., if you read a series of local times then it may help if you know that they are sorted: [Parsing of Ordered Timestamps in Local Time (to UTC) While Observing Daylight Saving Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26217427/4279).

Comment: I am now using this answer. However, can you please elaborate on ". If you know that the time corresponds to the summer time then use is_dst=True"? I want a generic function that converts all times as shown in my question. Can I just always set `is_dst=True`?

Comment: @Tommy: I've elaborated on `is_dst` flag.

Comment: just to make sure I understand: we set out clocks back at 11pm Eastern on date X to 10pm. So all times in [X: 10pm, X:10:59:59] actually happen twice. So a timestamp in this interval is "ambiguous". the `is_dst` flag determines how we resolve this ambiguity within this exact interval.

Comment: @Tommy: at 2 a.m. (as shown in the picture) the clocks are turned back by an hour and therefore the time between 1am and 2am occurs twice (the code example use 1:30am -- in the middle of the interval).

Answer (score 2):

First of all `'%s'` is not supported on all platforms , its actually working for you because your platform C library’s `strftime()` function (that is called by Python) supports it. This function is what is causing the issue most probably, I am guessing its not timezone aware , hence when taking difference from epoch time it is using your local timezone, which is most probably EST(?)

Instead of relying on `'%s'` , which only works in few platforms (linux, I believe) , you should manually subtract the datetime you got from epoch (`1970/1/1 00:00:00`) to get the actual seconds since epoch . Example -

```
e = (utc_dt - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
```

Demo -

```
>>> (utc_dt - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
1429578727.0
```

This correctly corresponds to the date-time you get.

Comment: i did `return (utc_dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()`, is this the same?

Comment: If that is working for you, for some reason, only this works for me - `(utc_dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()` . you need the `.replace()` because `utcfromtimestamp()` returns a datetime with tzinfo set to `None` (as given in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) )

Comment: @Tommy: [`strftime('%s')` is not the only issue in your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727761/4279)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why but you have to remove the timezone info from your `utc_dt` before using `%s` to print it.

```
e = int(utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=None).strftime("%s"))
print(e)
return e
```

Comment: Is your local time UTC? this does not produce any difference for me.

Comment: @AnandSKumar My local time is US/Eastern. It produced the same `1429578727` for me in a python shell on OS X. It is probably my system's `%s` implementation.