# How to make a time object TZ aware without changing the value?

Tags: python, django, pytz

I'm working on a django project and i got confused about the timezones.

I have a campaing object, it has `publish_start` and `publish_end` dates.

example output from the console;

```
campaingObject.publish_start
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0)

campaingObject.publish_end
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 28, 10, 10)
```

I want to get campaing objects that are active now. That means publish start is less then current time, end time is greater then current time.

When i call:

```
datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 28, 5, 42, 37, 448415)
```

This result is not in my timezone. I can get my own time info with

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul'))
```

but this time i can not compare values to find which objects are active right now.

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul')) > campaingObject.publish_end
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

How can i compare this times to find which objects are active right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `make_aware` function from django on your naive datetime objects. You will then have to specify the time zone of your naive timestamps.

```
now_ts = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul'))
now_ts > make_aware(campaingObject.publish_end, pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware

On the other hand, you could also use the `make_naive` function to remove the timezone information from your now() timestamp:

```
now_ts = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul'))
now_naive = make_naive(now_ts, pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul'))
now_naive > campaingObject.publish_end
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_naive

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul')) > campaingObject.publish_end
>    TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
> ```
>
> How can i compare this times to find which objects are active right now?

Use timezone-aware datetime objects everywhere. If [`USE_TZ = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) then django uses timezone-aware datetime objects internally. In particular, [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) returns an aware datetime object.

[`timezone.localtime(timezone.now())`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) returns the current time in the [current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-current-time-zone) -- [you don't need to call `timezone.localtime()` explicitly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage) -- the current time zone is used for rendering automatically. You could use [`activate('Europe/Istanbul')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) to change the current time zone if the default time zone [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) is not suitable for the request.

> How to make a time object TZ aware without changing the value?

If you've configured `USE_TZ=True`; you shouldn't see naive datetime objects. To attach the [current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-current-time-zone) to a naive datetime object, call [`dt = timezone.make_aware(naive_dt)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware).

In general, you could call `pytz_timezone.localize()` method directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul')
now = datetime.now(tz) # get the current time
then = tz.localize(datetime.strptime('2015-09-15 17:05', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                   is_dst=None)
```

Here're [more details about what is `is_dst` flag and why do you need it, see *"Can I just always set is_dst=True?"* section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32727761/4279).