# Compare time with timezone to now

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a string time coming from a third party (external to my python program), and I need to compare that time to right now.  How long ago was that time?

How can I do this?

I've looked at the `datetime` and `time` libraries, as well as `pytz`, and can't find an obvious way to do this.  It should automatically incorporate DST because the third party doesn't explicitly state its offset, only the timezone (US/Eastern).

I've tried this, and it fails:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('June 10, 2016 12:00PM', '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
dtEt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
now = datetime.datetime.now()

now - dtEt
```

TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Please post some examples of what you have tried and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question Zack! I've had this problem myself.

Here's some code to do so:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import calendar
import pytz

def howLongAgo(thirdPartyString, timeFmt):
  # seconds since epoch
  thirdPartySeconds = calendar.timegm(time.strptime(thirdPartyString, timeFmt))
  nowSecondsUTC = time.time()

  # hour difference with DST
  nowEastern = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
  nowUTC = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
  timezoneOffset = (nowEastern.day - nowUTC.day)*24 + (nowEastern.hour - nowUTC.hour) + (nowEastern.minute - nowUTC.minute)/60.0

  thirdPartySecondsUTC = thirdPartySeconds - (timezoneOffset * 60 * 60)
  return nowSecondsUTC - thirdPartySecondsUTC

howLongAgo('June 09, 2016 at 06:22PM', '%B %d, %Y at %I:%M%p') 
# first argument always provided in ET, either EDT or EST
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Now my thermostat will maintain the perfect temperature!

Comment: 1- your answer assumes that US/Eastern has a constant utc offset—it is incorrect 2- if you know that the input time is in US/Eastern timezone then use `(datetime.now(pytz.utc) - pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.strptime(thirdPartyString, timeFmt), is_dst=None)).total_seconds()` to find the difference in seconds.

Comment: Localize is definitely a better answer, may have to do some error handling for the one hour / year that is ambiguously defined (when DST actually occurs).  My solution assumes that the difference between Eastern and UTC is the same for "now" and the `thirdParty` time (so it won't work for a time six months ago).

Comment: `is_dst` parameter handles ambiguous and non-existent times. In particular, `is_dst=None` raises an exception in such cases (you can choose a different error handling strategy more suitable for your specific application).

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

To fix the `TypeError`, use timezone aware datetime objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

now = datetime.now(tz) # the current time (it works even during DST transitions)
then_naive = datetime.strptime('June 10, 2016 12:00PM', '%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
then = tz.localize(then_naive, is_dst=None) 
time_difference_in_seconds = (now - then).total_seconds()
```

`is_dst=None` causes an exception for ambiguous/non-existing times. You could also use `is_dst=False` (default) or `is_dst=True`, see [python converting string in localtime to UTC epoch timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723834/4279).